# Why do EventListeners stop working after manipulating the z-property and changing stage.quality?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Currently one of our teams suffers from a very strange phenomena: after manipulating the `z` property of a `MovieClip` and changing the stage quality some event listeners of nested `MovieClips` seem to disappear (or at least not react to the proper events any longer).

The problem also *only* appears when doing both, changing the stage quality **and** manipulating the `z`property.

Here is a simple class demonstrating the issue:

```
package {
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.StageQuality;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class StageQualityTestDemo extends MovieClip {
    private static const OVER_COLOR:uint = 0x13ff37;
    private static const OUT_COLOR:uint = 0x000000;
    private static const BACK_COLOR:uint = 0xdeadc0de;
    private var _qualitySetting:int = 0;
    private var _zoom:Number = 0.0;
    private var _mainsprite:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    private var _button:MovieClip = new MovieClip();


    public function StageQualityTestDemo() {
        initDemo();
    }

    private function initDemo():void {
        this.addChild(_mainsprite);
        _mainsprite.addChild(_button);

        this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, handleMouseWheel);
        stage.quality = StageQuality.LOW;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        drawButtonCircle(OUT_COLOR);
        drawMainBackground(BACK_COLOR);
        _button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, handleMouseOver);
        _button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, handleMouseOut);
    }

    private function handleMouseOver(event:MouseEvent):void {
        drawButtonCircle(OVER_COLOR);
    }

    private function handleMouseOut(event:MouseEvent):void {
        drawButtonCircle(OUT_COLOR);
    }

    private function drawMainBackground(color:uint):void {
        var g:Graphics = _mainsprite.graphics;
        g.clear();
        g.beginFill(color);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        g.endFill();
    }

    private function drawButtonCircle(color:uint):void {
        var g:Graphics = _button.graphics;
        g.clear();
        g.beginFill(color);
        g.drawCircle(250, 250, 50);
        g.endFill();
    }

    private function handleMouseWheel(event:MouseEvent):void {
        var motion:Number = event.delta * 5;
        _zoom += motion;
        _mainsprite.z = _zoom;

        if (_zoom < 0 && _qualitySetting != 0 ) {
            _qualitySetting = 0;
            trace("setting LOW");
            stage.quality = StageQuality.LOW;
        }

        if (_zoom > 100 && _qualitySetting == 0 ) {
            _qualitySetting = 1;
            trace("setting HIGH");
            stage.quality = StageQuality.HIGH;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Can anyone give me a pointer what the heck is going on here? Why do the eventlisteners on the `_button` stop working when zoomed out and stage quality is `HIGH` but work again when zoomed in and stage quality is `LOW`? Help? Anyone?

---

**[Update]**

Based on @Amy Blankenship's suggestion, I've added some more `trace` statements. The result is that both `willTrigger()` and `hasEventListener()` report true but the handler functions still are not called.

Code changes:

```
[...]

private var _counter:int;

[...]

private function initDemo():void {
    this.addChild(_mainsprite);
    _mainsprite.addChild(_button);
    this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, handleMouseWheel);
    this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, handleMouseMove);
    stage.quality = StageQuality.LOW;
    stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
    stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
    drawButtonCircle(OUT_COLOR);
    drawMainBackground(BACK_COLOR);
    _button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, handleMouseOver);
    _button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, handleMouseOut);
}

private function handleMouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void {
    if (_counter++ % 50 == 0) {
        trace("_button.willTrigger(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER): " + _button.willTrigger(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER));
        trace("_button.willTrigger(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT): " + _button.willTrigger(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER));
        trace("_button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER): " + _button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER));
        trace("_button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT): " + _button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT));
    }
}

private function handleMouseOver(event:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("handleMouseOver");
    drawButtonCircle(OVER_COLOR);
}

private function handleMouseOut(event:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("handleMouseOut");
    drawButtonCircle(OUT_COLOR);
}

[...]
```

Trace output:

```
_button.willTrigger(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER): true
_button.willTrigger(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT): true
_button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER): true
_button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT): true
// moving the mouse over and off _button
handleMouseOver
handleMouseOut
_button.willTrigger(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER): true
_button.willTrigger(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT): true
_button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER): true
_button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT): true
// zooming out; handler methods no longer called
setting HIGH
_button.willTrigger(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER): true
_button.willTrigger(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT): true
_button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER): true
_button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT): true
_button.willTrigger(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER): true
_button.willTrigger(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT): true
_button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER): true
_button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT): true
_button.willTrigger(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER): true
_button.willTrigger(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT): true
_button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER): true
_button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT): true
_button.willTrigger(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER): true
_button.willTrigger(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT): true
_button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER): true
_button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT): true
// zooming back in; handler methods called again
setting LOW
handleMouseOver
handleMouseOut
_button.willTrigger(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER): true
_button.willTrigger(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT): true
_button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER): true
_button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT): true
handleMouseOver
_button.willTrigger(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER): true
_button.willTrigger(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT): true
_button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER): true
_button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT): true
handleMouseOut
_button.willTrigger(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER): true
_button.willTrigger(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT): true
_button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER): true
_button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT): true
handleMouseOver
handleMouseOut
```

**[/Update]**

Comment: Did you try to trace stage.getObjectsUnderPoint(stage.mouseX,stage.mouseY) and see if something capture your mouse event. Also isolate the issue by commenting out the stage quality stuff.

Comment: @Guillaume Malartre: I haven't tried `getObjectsUnderPoint()` yet, thanks for the tip. About the other thing, the problem only occurs when both things happen: if I remove the changing of `stage.quality` it works, if I remove the manipulation of the `z` property it also works. But if both happens it stops working. The team suffering from the problem alas cannot remove either operation from their code and the example above is already a simplified demonstration of the issue in their project.

Comment: you should fill a bug in adobe bug base at http://bugs.adobe.com/, also did you try to remove and re-add the eventlistener when you change those properties.

Comment: Also, try checking willTrigger or hasEventListener, to see if the listeners are, in fact, removed.

Comment: @Guillaume Malartre: I've tried removing and readding the listeners inside the `handleMouseWheel` method but the behavior didn't change. I guess I'm going to file a bug with Adobe on this one.

Comment: @Amy Blankenship: I've added some more `trace`s and now I'm really confused, because both `willTrigger()` and `hasEventListener()` say that the listeners are still there yet they are not called when moving the mouse over the button when zoomed out and `stage.quality == StageQuality.HIGH`.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd guess that the player is miscalculating the position of your button for mouse events, so it doesn't "know" the cursor is over the button.  What happens if you make the button extend a base class that listens to itself for mouse events and then dispatches a custom event on mouse over (though maybe this won't be needed if you encapsulate the logic--what you're doing is handling the display of rollover state)?

Comment: Try adding a stage mouse_move listener and check if you can hit your object with getObjectsUnderPoint() by moving your mouse everywhere =). And like Amy suggest, make a button that trigger some trace of your sprite position, take that point and convert it with point = parent.localToGlobal(point).

Comment: A question: You REALLY NEED to change stage quality while zooming?

Comment: @Marcelo de Assis Costa: Pretty much yes. One of our games uses vector graphics and switches `stage.quality` to low whenever the user zooms or pans around on the map. With the movement you barely notice the quality difference but it grants a huge performance boost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem resolved itself after the team where the bug originally occured did some more tests and investigation. I mentioned in my question that the shown code was only a simplified demonstration of the issue.

The original product is a Flex 4.1 application and uses vector graphics. When zooming or panning on the map we switch `stage.quality` to LOW because the difference is barely noticeable but with LOW quality the whole thing is significantly faster.

The bug caused lots of trouble for the team, since it happened to make some buttons in popups unresponsive, which basically broke some core functionality of the game. However, the issue apparently was related to some fade-in effect on these popups. The team removed the fade-in and now everything works alright...  o_O

*"Flash Player, y u no work like normal software?"*

I've [reported the issue to Adobe](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=2976709) and it was confirmed as a bug. I've already asked our other team for a detailed report of the circumstances the bug appeared in to attach to the tracked bug so somewhen during next week more information on the issue will be available.

Thank you all for your advice and suggestions. :)

Answer (score 3):

I find that using stage.quality = StageQuality.MEDIUM; instead of HIGH works. 
I know that flash z transforms actually work by converting the clips to bitmaps. And that bitmaps are not InteractiveObjects. I think you have found a flash player bug. 
But hopefully using medium stage quality for zoomed items will get you "good enough" quality to finish your project.

Answer (score 2):

I am also at a loss as to *why* the behavior is occurring, but I was able to find a workaround.

Reconstructing the display list lets you pick up on the mouse events again.  I do not know how practical this is for your situation; you mentioned this is a simplified version of your problem.  Regardless, here is the code that I am running.  I'm able to zoom in and change the quality of the stage while still handling the mouse events:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageQuality;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;

    public class AS3Playground extends MovieClip
    {
        private static const OVER_COLOR:uint = 0x13ff37;
        private static const OUT_COLOR:uint = 0x000000;
        private static const BACK_COLOR:uint = 0xdeadc0de;
        private var _qualitySetting:int = 0;
        private var _zoom:Number = 0.0;
        private var _mainsprite:MovieClip;
        private var _button:MovieClip;

        private var _lastKnownStageQuality:String;

        private var _counter:int;

        public function AS3Playground()
        {
            trace("AS3Playground() @"+getTimer());
            initDemo();
        }

        private function maintainDisplayOrder():void
        {
            addChild(_mainsprite);
            _mainsprite.addChild(_button);
        }

        private function initDemo():void
        {
            trace("initDemo() @"+getTimer());

            _mainsprite  = new MovieClip();
            _mainsprite.graphics.clear();
            _mainsprite.graphics.beginFill(BACK_COLOR);
            _mainsprite.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            _mainsprite.graphics.endFill();

            _button = new MovieClip();
            _button.graphics.clear();
            _button.graphics.beginFill(OUT_COLOR);
            _button.graphics.drawCircle(250, 250, 50);
            _button.graphics.endFill();

            maintainDisplayOrder();

            stage.quality = StageQuality.LOW;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

            _lastKnownStageQuality = stage.quality;

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, handleMouseWheel);
            _button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, handleMouseOver);
            _button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, handleMouseOut);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame, false, 0, true);
        }

        private function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
        {
            if (_counter++ % 50 == 0)
            {
                trace("onEnterFrame(event) @"+getTimer());
                trace("_button.willTrigger(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER): " + _button.willTrigger(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER));
                trace("_button.willTrigger(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT): " + _button.willTrigger(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER));
                trace("_button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER): " + _button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER));
                trace("_button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT): " + _button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT));
                trace("mouse: @("+mouseX+", "+mouseY+")");

                var buttonStageRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle();
                var buttonStageCoordinate:Point = _button.localToGlobal(new Point(0, 0));
                buttonStageRect.x = buttonStageCoordinate.x;
                buttonStageRect.y = buttonStageCoordinate.y;

                trace("_button stage area: @("+buttonStageRect.x+", "+buttonStageRect.y+") "+_button.width+"x"+_button.height);
                trace("hitTest? "+_button.hitTestPoint(mouseX, mouseY));
            }

            if (_lastKnownStageQuality != stage.quality)
            {
                trace("stage quality changed!");    
                maintainDisplayOrder();
                _lastKnownStageQuality = stage.quality;
            }
        }

        private function handleMouseOver(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace("handleMouseOver(event) @"+getTimer());
            drawButtonCircle(OVER_COLOR);
        }

        private function handleMouseOut(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace("handleMouseOut(event) @"+getTimer());
            drawButtonCircle(OUT_COLOR);
        }

        private function drawButtonCircle(color:uint):void
        {
            _button.graphics.clear();
            _button.graphics.beginFill(color);
            _button.graphics.drawCircle(250, 250, 50);
            _button.graphics.endFill();
        }

        private function handleMouseWheel(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace("handleMouseWheel(event) @"+getTimer());
            var motion:Number = event.delta * 5;
            _zoom += motion;
            _mainsprite.z = _zoom;

            if (_zoom < 0 && _qualitySetting != 0 )
            {
                _qualitySetting = 0;
                trace("setting LOW");
                stage.quality = StageQuality.LOW;
            }
            if (_zoom > 100 && _qualitySetting == 0 )
            {
                 _qualitySetting = 1;
                 trace("setting HIGH");
                 stage.quality = StageQuality.HIGH;
            }

            maintainDisplayOrder();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rebuilding the DisplayList is an interesting approach to the problem. I've tried removing and readding the EventListeners after the issue occured and it didn't help, so it's good to know that rebuilding the hierarchy helps (in case something like this happens again).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this could be your problem.
Flash does NOT support the MOUSE_WHEEL event.

There is a workaround using javascript code and the ExternalInterface.
Essentially the javascript intercepts the mouse wheel event and passed it to the flash Object under the cursor.

Here is the source code that solves this (including the comments:
http://code.google.com/p/contentdisplay/source/browse/trunk/source/com/earthbrowser/ebutils/MacMouseWheelHandler.as?r=20

Comment: Where the author says he's using a mac?

Comment: He does not say what platform he is on

Comment: I tested the code and I see the described problem on windows.

Comment: I use a Mac so I did not want to assume it was also failing on Windows

Comment: @eLouai: I did forget to mention what platform we're using. It is indeed Windows, sorry for the confusion. But thanks for the heads up, this may come in handy at some point since we're also targetting Mac with some of our products. :)